# Comparing rows count for two different tables Pentaho

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlite, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I want to compare two row counts for two tables from two different connexions.
 I've tried to get the number of rows for each different table by executing
`Select count(*) as count1 from Table1`
and
 `Select count(*) as count2 from Table2`
in two different *Execute SQL Script* steps, as in the following screenshot, but I have no idea how to proceed.
[image]
Especially, I want to get the two different counts and compare them then branch with success/failure on whether they're equal or not, respectively.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy. There is a step called `Evaluate rows number in a table`. This both gets a row count from a table and tests it against a value. The value can come from a variable in the Job (note Job, not Transform).

So all you need to do is create a variable with a `Set variables` task, get the row count from one of your tables and then execute the Evaluate rows task. The following job will do just that.

[image: Count Compare]

The transform to get the row count for the other table is very simple. Just execute a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {tblname}` in a `Table input` step and flow the output to a `Set variables` step in a transform. Be sure to mark the variable as valid in the parent job.

[image: Set Row Counts]

You can also execute an SQL against a connection with the JavaScript step which would avoid creating the transform, but I prefer to avoid scripting when possible.

Comment: what is the usefulness of the first Set Variables step in the parent job ?

Comment: It actually sets the values in the parent job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Table Compare step, everything you need is here, regards
[image: table compare]